# How can I edit text displayed in "Estimate Shipping and Tax" module when there are no available shipping methods?

Tags: shipping, magento-community, ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-methods

The way our Magento store is setup, there are instances where the shipping method is hidden/unavailable and the text in the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" module area simply says "No Available Shipping Methods"
I would like to edit this text to be more descriptive and let them know to contact us for other options.

The question is, where is this text located so that I can modify it?

Running Magento 1.9.0.1 CE
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try updating the "Displayed Error Message" in Admin -> system -> Config -> Shipping Methods

Comment: R.S Yes, I have modified the "Displayed Error Message" field. Unfortunately, the shipping method isn't displaying an error. Therefore the error text isn't displayed. The existing shipping methods simply do not apply in this situation, so there are no shipping methods available to display. Which is why "No Available Shipping Methods" is being displayed instead of the error message.

Comment: Does your shipping method has a option for "Show method if not applicable" if so set it to "yes"

Comment: Maybe I need to better explain the situation. We do not want to display a shipping option in some cases. When this happens, we would like to display a custom message to contact us for further options. Since there is already a message displayed in this situation, I simply need to find where that message is so that I can customize it.

Comment: Try enable magento path hints which should show the block/template that is displaying this info

Comment: @R.S Thank you for the suggestion. That helped me to see that the text was being added by a 3rd party extension we use to manage shipping rules. I was able to find and edit the text using that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enable magento path hints which should show the block/template that is displaying this info.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

- log into the magento back-end admin.
- Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu.
- Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED.
- Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're talking about the checkout page, which in that case, the file is located in template->checkout->cart->shipping.phtml. You can modify the message there. I hope that provided some kind of guidance!